# ViewChild inside a dom if in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a reference to an element which is inside dom-if using `ViewChild`. Actually I am using `mat-stepper` and want to navigate to 2nd step directly. Following is the snippets of my code;

**.html**

```
<mat-vertical-stepper  #stepper *ngIf="showStepper">
```

**component.ts**

```
 @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      firstCtrl: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      secondCtrl: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
      
    });


                this.stepper.selectedIndex = 1;
  }
```

I want to navigate to 2nd step(1st index) directly. For this I am using ViewChild, but since mat-stepper is inside a `dom-if`, `this.stepper` is coming out to be undefined.
Here is the `stackblitz` link to my code:

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nhwms)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Timeout to shift the execution, and use a condition to do it only if the stepper exists : [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nhwms-wyamna?file=app/stepper-vertical-example.ts)

```js
setTimeout(() => this.stepper ? this.stepper.selectedIndex = 1 : null);
```

Also, consider binding the click on your button to `ngOnInit` (although you should create a new function, that will be called by the button & ngOnInit). Also consider shifting that timeout into the subscribe.

If you don't display the data, there's no point in having it stored.